# Zookeeper folder missing in Solr Cloud admin UI

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I have 3 Solr 7.3 and 3 zookeeper 3.4.12 servers. When I look in the [cloud](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/cloud-screens.html) tree I can see the configsets from zookeeper but I am missing the zookeeper folder. Is that an indication of an error? I am asking this because I am unable to create a collection without getting a timeout.
And I am looking for every clue I can get.

[image: Solr admin UI cloud tab]

Trying to resolve this error
[image]

Comment: That directory is usually empty, so I don't think that's relevant for your error. What's the actual error and if it references a node, what does the log on that node say? And what version of Solr are we talking about?

Comment: Version 7.3.1 and ZK 3.4.12. The error log is very long but it's all about timeout. It's like the servers don't now about each other

Comment: Are you sure they actually _can_ talk to each other? They're not firewalled locally or something similar? Both Solr and Zookeeper-ports are open? How about telnet from one server to the solr port of the other server?

Comment: It's running on AWS and I can telnet from ZK too Solr and from Solr to ZK. Solr is running on port 8983 and communicate with ZK on 2181. ZK uses 2888 and 3888 for internal communication

Comment: Not that I think it matters, but Solr 7.3.1 ships with ZK 3.4.11 - not .12. While a dotversion shouldn't be a problem ...

Comment: If you haven't, I'd also try just creating the directory. Maybe Solr or ZK uses it for watching to trigger syncs.

Comment: Thanks I will work on it tomorrow when I am at work

Comment: Great, if you could add the actual stacktrace as well that might be helpful.

Comment: Everything is now working. I made a mistake in the security group and @MatsLindh was right. Not all solr nodes where able to "talk" to each other.